# How to check if a text file has generated in a particular path or not in C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

one .txt file is getting exported inside the path  - D:\work\int\retail\store\export after i run a Stored procedure. Now i want to validate in C# whether the .txt file has come or not in this path. I am using the below syntax according to which file.exists() is still returning false even though .txt file is there in the export location.what's going wrong here?Any help will be appreciated on this.how can i get the latest file name coming in this location dynamically and pass to this below query?

```
var FilePath = @"D:\work\int\retail\store\export";
            if(File.Exists(FilePath))
            {
                //do this
            }
```

Comment: you have not supplied the file name, or you have missed extension if file name is export

Comment: your path points to a Folder not a file. File, expects some extension.

Comment: @SaketChoubey this file is getting generated from a stored procedure, the file name must start with IG_Range and after that whatever comes will change after each run. The file must be .txt as well

Comment: @SaketChoubey File name are like  IG_Range_20160720_192236, IG_Range_20160720_191938. Only IG_Range is constant rest is dynamic

Comment: @Tigran the .txt file is getting produced inside D:\work\int\retail\store\export. now how to fetch the name of the latest .txt file here if the name is changing after each run dyamically?

Comment: @SaketChoubey what will come in the variable file???? and which directory is it going, u have not mentioned any path also.

Comment: @SaketChoubey as of now .ok and .txt 2 files are there and it is picking .ok file name in the variable File. how to make it to take only the latest txt file?  Also the condition File.Exists(File.ToString()) is still returning false, can u please help?

Comment: @SumitDwivedi please check edited Answer.

Answer (score 3):

for checking if specific files exists on a path use File.Exists(path), which will return a boolean indicating whether the file at path exists. In your case

```
if(File.Exists(@"D:\work\int\retail\store\export\one.txt"))
{
    //do this
}
```

In your example you are missing the filename.

If you want to fetch the latest file from some directory use this code.

```
    var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\work\int\retail\store\export");
    var File = directory.GetFiles()
                 .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)
                 .First();
```

You have to create a variavble of DirectoryInfo Class which takes directory path as parameter, Here I have passed your directory path `D:\work\int\retail\store\export`, Now `GetFiles()` function returns all the files inside the directory and I have sorted them in Descending order by `LastWriteTime` property of files, and fetched the first file which will be the latest file in the directory. Hope it helps.

To get the .txt file only Please use below code. It will get you the latest txt file.

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Saket\Downloads\");
var File = directory.GetFiles().Where(c=>c.Extension == ".txt")
                         .OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime)                         
                         .First();
```

Comment: The file name must start with IG_Range. after this , anything comes dynamically which changes after each execution, now how to track this?

Comment: Okay, So i believe this file you are generating through SP, Right? Can you change you SP if required?

Comment: how to get the filename from that location?

Comment: @SumitDwivedi Use this to get all the files in the directory 
IEnumerable<string> items = Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(@"C:\Users\Saket\Downloads\"); Hope it helps

Comment: @SumitDwivedi Please mark answered if your query is resolved. So it wont show as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention your text file name in the path, if your txt file is called x.txt for example, you need to write the path as var FilePath = @"D:\work\int\retail\store\export\x.txt";

Comment: the file is getting generated dynamically. how to fetch the filename and pass that here??